# The difference between function, class, method, object and constructor?

Tags: oop

I have always struggled remembering key words in Object Oriented Programming, I feel like they are all used interchangeably, so can someone please take the time to explain the The difference between function, class, method, object and constructor? It does not really differ from language to language so any explanation will help but I'm learning Java and Dart right now. Thank you!

Comment: Function might be used interchangeably with method and class might be used interchangeably with object, but other than that I'm not sure where you've seen them used in place of one another?

Comment: This is a general software programming question, nothing related with the tags. Closed

Comment: Anyone who uses "class" interchangeably with "object" must understand almost nothing about OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "class" is a category of like things (think of the biological classification, or the set theory term (the thing that is bigger than a set), or just the word "classification.")  If you need a more prosaic way to remember it, all the seats in first class are the same size and shape as each other, as are all the seats in economy class.

Objects are instances of some class.  There can be many objects of a given class.  Every object is unique from every other object; objects have *identity*.  (Seats in economy class have seat numbers.)

Constructors make (construct!) objects.  A class has constructors, with which you make objects of that class.  The role of a constructor is to create an object with its representational invariants established (that is, create objects in a valid state.)

Functions/methods are behaviors, usually associated with a class.

Comment: A good answer overall, but I don't think we should be teaching people that functions and methods are the same thing. That's a very Java-centric viewpoint and will trip people up if they move to a language like Python or C++ that has *actual* functions that are distinct from methods in a formal sense.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I think perhaps it is you who is bringing a specific language's interpretation to your reading.  Functions and methods both do refer to (usually named) behaviors.  But that doesn't mean they are synonyms.  Some languages have one but not the other; some have both.  (The difference between a function and method in Python is the same as the difference between a static and instance method in Java or C# or C++.  But they are still both named behaviors, and still usually associated with classes.)